# Any alternative ways to find hostels than hostelworld or hostelbookers

Tags: accommodation, hostels

Are there any other reliable ways to find cheap, hostel like accommodation last minute, without using hostel world or hostel bookers?

I'm currently finding all accommodation booked up on these two sites :-\

Comment: Have you tried phoning the hostels of interest? They don't always make all their rooms available through agencies, sometimes they keep some back themselves

Comment: It's not uncommon that hostels distribute their available beds/rooms through 2 or 3 systems. They also often keep a few for "walk-ins". So, contacting them might be an option. Another option is checking the websites frquently. The available "spare" beds may be put online if there are no "walk-ins" or if there is someone  not showing up.

Comment: booking.com and agoda.com has filters to narrow down your search to hostels.

Comment: @Gagravarr, nsn - thanks guys.  Contacting the hostels directly seamed to solve any accommodation problems I had. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to Scotland you can use http://www.hostel-scotland.co.uk/ for independent hostels

and http://www.syha.org.uk/ for Scottish Youth Hostels (you don't have to be young to use these).

For other countries you can use Hostelling International http://www.hihostels.com